# Access specific page using time inserted in database

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I was using this

```
$end = $row['EndPro'];
    $email1= $_SESSION['Email'];

        $stmt = $con -> prepare ("SELECT 
       * 
            FROM 
       users 
            WHERE 
       Email = '$email1'
            AND 

       TrustStatus = 1
        AND

     now() < '$end'    

       LIMIT 1");

       $stmt-> execute ( array($email1));
       $row =$stmt -> fetch();
       $count = $stmt-> rowCount();


       if($count>0 ){
```

To give people access to specific page using the date inserted (ProEnd)
so if today's date is smaller than the date inserted, the person would have an  access into the page

The problem is that if I change the date and the time on my PC, I can access the page and trick the system even if the time inserted in database was higher than the current time

How can I make a date that is related to mysql&database not to the PC's date?

Comment: It's because your PC is the system where the database gets the data to compare. The user can't do the same "trick".

Comment: You always have system time in the database and user can't manipulate. If you have DB/PHP on your pc - only then can it affect.